# "Laser" Android 7-inch tablet connects to the internet without WiFi access to router

Tags: wi-fi, internet

I have a "Laser" 7-inch Android Go tablet, model # MID-789.  I do not normally use it for internet work, but it is useful as a 2FA device, for which I usually wake up the WiFi and use my router for the connection.

Some weeks ago I lit it up and without thinking I touched the [Okta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.okta.android.mobile.oktamobile) icon and did my business.  Shutting it down, I realised I had not used the WiFi at all.  I tested this deliberately this morning, same result.  The tablet will even look for updates regardless of the WiFi status.  (There aren't any, it's that basic.)

I have searched through the Settings, very thoroughly indeed, but I cannot see anything that looks or even smells like connectivity.  It did occur to me that maybe there's a 4/5G sitting in there, but definitely there is no SIM or similar device.  So what gives?  Do all tablets have this magical ability?

Comment: Based on your description I don't see the point why you think the device had some sort of network connection. May be this is related to `Okta` - whatever that is. In case of third party apps please always include a link to the app in an app store.

Comment: @Robert - Okta is a 2FA verification app, at < https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.okta.android.mobile.oktamobile >.  I fail to see how an app can manifest a wireless communication channel.  If WiFi is off so my router can't see the tablet, then how does the tablet manage to communicate with Okta?  That's all I'm asking.

Comment: I am not sure how Okta works, but for generating a TOPT codes 2FA apps don't need internet access. They simply generate it based on the current time. So if the shown 2FA code(s) change periodically (e.g. every minute) then most likely it is a [TOTP code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_one-time_password).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp. Problem resolved.  The Okta app is the digital version of your bank's security key: the one you press the button and it gives you a sequence to type into your banking app. NO CONNECTIVITY NEEDED. This is a saga of poor design:

- 1. Okta's GUI is uninformative, although it doesn't actually SAY it doesn't need to be connected;
- 2. The Google Search Bar which auto-loads at start-up doesn't help as it continuously cycles through search suggestions, and this already had me wondering;
- 3. There is a backgound pervasive assumption that the user will always be connected so the need to remind the user is never asserted; and
- 4. I blindly assumed I needed to be connected.

The Laser tablet only cost me Au$70.00 in 2021, so I don't expect much from it. But given that Okta is a major player I did expect MUCH better GUIdance.

Thank you everyone for your words of wisdom.

Answer (score 1):

Connectivity does not happen by magic. The most plausible answer is that your Wi-Fi was not as turned off as you thought.

To test this, power down your Wi-Fi hub, and then see if you have connectivity. If you do, check if you're mistakenly using a neighbour's Wi-Fi.

Comment: When I go to "Settings>Network&Internet>WiFi" and WiFi is greyed, "Off" in text and the switch icon is greyed, then WiFi is very definitely no enabled.  FWIW, Bluetooth is also disabled.  I did run a test of my router.  The GUI shows a list of connected devices, which in normal circumstances would be my PC and a telephony ATA for VOIP.  My Laser tablet would have shown up as a device had it been detected.  I know this because I have seen it previously several times dating from when I first set it up.  It would also have been visible in the DHCP routing list.

Comment: Your suggestion about mistakenly using a neighbour's WiFi is quite rational.  I have seen several networks listed as "unsecured", and I always wonder why anyone would be so careless.  But if the tablet's WiFi is OFF, then how can it make any connection?

Comment: @SomeBloke: When you seem to have something impossible happening in the real world, then one (or more) of the pieces of information you're using is wrong. You seem to be in that situation, so it's time to suspect the information you are using. If you have connectivity when the tablet *says* its wi-fi is off, try powering down your wi-fi hub, and see if you still have it. If you do, take the tablet three miles away, and see if you still have it.